# Get Eclipse to recognise CSS included via context in Spring MVC project

Tags: css, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

I've read many different ways to include CSS into a Spring MVC project and they all load fine when deployed onto a server:

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<c:url value='/css/style.css' />" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/MyApp/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

However, it seems Eclipse is not too happy unless I provide a relative path (eg. `../../css/style.css`) but that path will obviously not load when deployed. If I use either of the three methods above, I get a red wavy line below the path with the error:

```
Undefined CSS file ("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/style.css").
```

All the classes used from that stylesheet will also have a similar error:

```
Undefined CSS class (class-name).
```

Am I missing something or do I have to live with this and turn off the warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too experienced this problem, and found a bug has been reported in the eclipse WTP Webresources project on githib:

https://github.com/angelozerr/eclipse-wtp-webresources/issues/37

If/When this is fixed, our annoying red squiggly lines will be a thing of the past!

Answer (score 0):

I gave up searching for an ideal answer and instead, restructured my project so that the relative path of the physical files reflects the logical path when the app is deployed. Makes your choice of structure a little rigid but at least it satisfies both development-time and run-time environments.

Final answer:

```
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```