# Eclipse: Ignore "Undefined CSS class" warning

Tags: css, eclipse, validation, warnings

I use Spring and have found this answer to similar question, however it not at all satisfactory since it requires changing project structure:
[Get Eclipse to recognise CSS included via context in Spring MVC project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396242/get-eclipse-to-recognise-css-included-via-context-in-spring-mvc-project)

So the question is, can I somehow set Eclipse to ignore "Undefined CSS class" warning.

It's not just about Spring, I might have some CSS classes I use in JavaScript that are not present in CSS spreadsheet or any other reason. The warning is shown on every element on html that uses css class that it cannot find, say:

```
<div class="js-something">Something</div>
```

This class is not going to be defined in .css file since it is only used in JavaScript.  Same thing with Spring where .css is connected with:

```
<link href="<c:url value='/css/style.css'/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Or in AngularJS project where html files are added with ng-include. This warning is really barely helpful, it probably should be even disabled by default. I've looked all through Eclipse settings but couldn't find any way to ignore this kind of warnings. Can anybody help me get rid of those?

Comment: Even though you link to another question, you might want to explain what the problem is.

Comment: @Rvervuurt The question is in the title. Added to the question body though so it's more clear.

Comment: We need more context, especially since Eclipse's CSS Editor doesn't do *any* validation. What "kind" of `Problem` is it in the Problems View? Can you attach a screenshot of the error message?

Comment: @nitind Ok, I guess I didn't state it that clear again, sorry. Updated the question once again. It's the warning in html on any class that Eclipse can't find in css files. Say you have a Spring project where CSS is connected via context - that means every <div class="something"> will be marked as warning since it cannot find class "something". Or if your project isn't Spring and css is connected as usual, every <div class="js-something"> that you plan to use only in JavaScript will also be marked with "Undefined CSS class" warning.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Allright, I've found it. Funnily enough, it is under "Validation" if you edit project preferences, but not in overall preferences, that's why I couldn't find it when searching preferences by "Validation".

In **project preferences**: Web Resources -> Validation -> CSS

In **overall preferences**: Web -> HTML Files -> Web Resources -> CSS

Finally my projects are no longer riddled with yellow markers.

Comment: Sounds like you have https://github.com/angelozerr/eclipse-wtp-webresources installed. That's not a surprise, right?

Comment: @nitind Well, I don't think I installed those specifically, I think they got included with some packs I installed with Eclipse Marketplace (from the installation history it looks like it has something to do with AngularJS for Eclipse).

Comment: spend hours looking for it just to realize the CSS validation was folded :D